# Is TEventLog component thread-safe?

Tags: multithreading, freepascal, lazarus

I use TEventLog component to debug my application, log all steps in order to fully verify that is working properly.

Is TEventLog thread safe, I am writing from multiple threads using the same instance of TEventLog. Is it wrong, should I use critical sections when writting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is thread safe. I don't see anything done for it. Moreover it is a TComponent, and most tcomponents are for designtime use and not threadsafe.

So yes, probably you must serialize yousrself.

Comment: Didn't knew you are in the staff of fpc, my respects.Keep up the amaizing work!